# Java Repeat String Unless Stop is entered

Tags: java, string, loops

I just started using Java, and I'm having trouble with loops. I have to make a program where a user enters a string, and unless they hit stop, they will be asked to enter another string. However, if the user enters string, it will output how many strings were odd(length), how many strings were even(length) and how many strings contained the word dog. Can somebody here give me the basics on how I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: Post some code to provide context to what you mean by "hitting stop".  I'm not sure if you mean typing the word "stop" or hitting a button or what.

Comment: Yeah typing the word stop...sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I know how to get the program to output the # of strings that are odd/even and the # of strings that contain the word dog.

I just don't know how to get the output to repeat in the loop.
How do I get "Please enter another string" to repeat as long as the input isn't "stop"? 

Literally have no clue what I'm doing here. Do while loop maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Not certain what you mean by hitting stop but you could use a loop (this is pseudocode and you will have to convert to Java on your own).  I am assuming that you know how to use the various string functions in Java, such as length() and substring().

```
System.out.print("Enter a string or 'stop' to end")
inputStr = myScanner.nextLine()
While not stop
// The if else determines whether length is even or odd and increments accordingly

   If inputStr.length % 2 == 0
      even++
   else
      odd++

   // find a dog if one exists
   If inputStr.indexOf("dog") > -1
      dog++

  // prompt for another string or stop`
   System.out.print("Enter a string or 'stop' to end")
   inputStr = myScanner.nextLine()
End While
```

Note: This is not precise java.  I did not end lines with ; etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually messed up the question. Like the output question is "Please enter a string or enter stop to finish"

So if the user inputs anything other than stop, it will output "Please enter another string.
However, if the user inputs stop, it will output how many strings have an odd length, how many strings have an even length, and how many strings contain the word dog. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please learn how to use code formatting!

Comment: When I actually write code, I will be sure to do that.

Comment: Kenneth>>> 
Andrew, if you have nothing to contribute, just don't comment. I started Java less than a month ago, and I've been doing fine other than loops. 

Kenneth, the code that you provided I have, so thanks for confirming that I have that correctly. My problem is getting the output to repeat, unless I hit stop.

I'm guessing something along the lines of while
 (inputString !="stop");
System.out.println("Please enter another string)

And sorry, I don't know how to use code formatting.

Comment: Before the loop, prompt the user to enter a string or to stop.  I am assuming you are probably using a scanner and storing your input in a string variable.  In my example I can it inputStr so I will continue to.  You while loop then needs to be something like 'While( !inputStr.equals("stop")).  Then at the bttom just before the end of the while loop, you would again ask the user to enter a string or stop and assign their response to inputStr.

Comment: Yep, I am using Scanner. And I prompt the user to enter a string or stop, then they enter a string. Then after that it says "Please enter another string" but doesn't allow them to input anything...and I'm using inputString as well.

Comment: See previous comment, since I was editing when you read and responded.

Comment: Thanks so much man, everything worked out perfectly. I really appreciate it.

Comment: That is the easy part.  You should already know how to print stuff.  My code was not meant to be your project.  I expected you to figure out a bit of it.

Comment: Embarrassing but the whole problem that I had was that I outputted "Please enter another string" as an infinite loop.